# CS50 - debug50 isn't working after update

Tags: python, c, cs50

```
runoff/ $ debug50 ./runoff a b c
Launching VS Code debugger...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/debug50", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debug50/__main__.py", line 72, in main
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(launch(args.PROGRAM, extra_args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debug50/__main__.py", line 90, in launch
    source = list(filter(lambda source_file: program in source_file, get_source_files(program)))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

After I updated the web IDE for CS50, I keep getting this error whenever I try to launch debug50. I don't know what to do. It was working just fine.

Obs: I'm setting the breakpoints, I didn't miss this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this same issue. I'm wondering if an update to debug50 has been made. Here's how I got it to work.

Try omitting the `./` from your command line script, so long as you are in the directory containing your program.

e.g.
`debug50 runoff a b c`